# Derive one class from another dynamically

Tags: c#, signalr

I have code like this:

```
class Hub 
{
   this is SignalR base class .. 
}

interface IBar
{
  some methods ...
}

[MyHub]
class Bar : IBar
{
  some methods ...
}
```

now i want to dynamically generate something like this

```
class Bar : Hub, IBar
{

}
```

Is there any possible way to do this.
I want to create method that return me a type Bar.
A main  concept is to decouple my dll with implementation of Bar from SignalR dll.
thats why i want to create this inheritence dynamically

Comment: There are lots of examples on the web for generating run-time-compiled code. And of course, doing so you can build the class however you like, including inheriting another class if you like. So, what have you tried? What happened? What did it do instead? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: for example, you could create a dynamically-generated class that inherits `TextReader`, overriding the interesting bits, and then pass an instance of that to any type that needs a `TextReader`. Just as you can dynamically generate code and compile it at run-time, you can create instances of such code and use them just as you'd use any other object instance. Having an inherited base class just makes it _easier_, since there's a compile-time type in that case that can be used.

Comment: When you say "dynamically", do you mean dynamically at runtime, or when?